# Where can I find a tax collector to kill for Tax Evasion?

Tags: achievements, assassins-creed-revelations

I'm trying to finish up the single player achievements in *Assassins Creed: Revelations*, but can't seem to ever find a tax collector to earn the following achievement:

> **Tax Evasion**: Get your money back from a Templar tax collector.

Is the tax collector triggered by any specific events, in certain memories, or completely random? Are there areas where they are more likely to show up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found one running around randomly, but I've only seen one, period.  They show up like the Borgia Messenger does in previous games, the icon looks like a red money bag.

Over on [this thread](http://www.trueachievements.com/achievement.aspx?achievementid=157173) is a supposedly repeatable way of getting one to spawn, by hiding near the Hagia Sophia tunnel entrance and waiting for a particular bank deposit in the day cycle, when one will almost always spawn.

Here's the related video:

Answer (score 3):

From what I have read, it seems to be easiest to find a tax collector if you are near a bank when the deposits come in. That seems to be when they are most likely to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Templar tax collector waiting for the bank deposit near the tunnel entrace of Haggia Sophia. After the deposit was made, I went to the bank and checked the summary of all my building but didn't withdraw any money. Then I ran around and the red icon for the Templar tax collector appeared.

Just after him and press do a hook sweep to get your money back.